# Change font automatically when typing CJK characters, possibly lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, cjk

The title says it all already.

I found how to change fonts with `fontspec` and lualatex, however I wonder if there is an easy way to mix Latin characters with Japanese characters without explicitly specifying the font all the time. So I can have the classic computer modern for english and another font for Japanese.

`xeCJK` solves this problem in xelatex, but I could not make it work in lualatex. Maybe the switch could be painless, but maybe there is a solution for lualatex?

Comment: Investigate `luatex-ja` package.

Answer (score 9):

A simple example follows.
For details, see documents of luatex-ja package.

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagella-Regular}
\setmainjfont{IPAexMincho}
\begin{document}
This is a test. 漢字のテスト。 This is a test.
\end{document}
```