# american-apa citation using biber with japanese title

Tags: biblatex, biber, japanese

I'm writing a document which is entirely written in English.
However, I have to cite a Japanese source.
I'm using MikTex (and there's no way to change to texlive).

Is there a way to cite the Japanese document in an "all" English document?
I'm using apa Style with American language setting and biber.

Comment: Welcome. I would simply use the english transliteration instead of the japanese script. Chances are high, your readers can't read the japanese script anyway.

Comment: The citation rules of my university require the original title as it is. I also think it makes searching for the document easier.

Comment: Depending on how well your document setup can fathom Japanese script that could be as easy as filling the `title` field with Japanese script. Can you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your document setup so we know what you can use.

Comment: Maybe [Change font automatically when typing CJK characters, possibly lualatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240507/change-font-automatically-when-typing-cjk-characters-possibly-lualatex) will answer your question?

Comment: I tried lualatex. It worked but it is really slow.
My current "solution" is to put a CJK-Environment inside of my .bib-File. This is genereated into the bibliography and displays the Japanese letters. This is not a very comfortable and beautiful solution. However, I have only one Japanese reference. So it is okay.

Comment: @GNA: The same question references [xecjk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) package for XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution the CJKuft8 package.
I put following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}  
\newenvironment{Japanese}{%
\CJKfamily{min}%
\CJKtilde
\CJKnospace}{}
```

This allows us to open an Environment which can display Japanese characters like this:

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
\begin{Japanese}
日本語
\end{Japanese}
\end{CJK}
```

This environment is also possible in a .bib file.

```
@Electronic{somesrc,
  author   = {{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Japanese}橋本\end{Japanese}\end{CJK}}},
  title    = {{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Japanese}テスト\end{Japanese}\end{CJK}}},
  year     = {2016},
  url      = {http://www.some-japanese-site.co.jp},
  language = {Japanese},
  urldate  = {2016-08-05}
}
```

Note that theres an extra pair of {} around the environments in the author and title field to prevent biblatex from splitting up the field and therefore destroying the CJK environment.

It's the quickest solution I found so far without changing to another latex version. This is tested with pdflatex on Windows (MikTeX) and Linux (texlive).

---

**UPDATE:**
For some time now, biber doesn't handle this correctly. It creates too many braces in the *.bbl file. This can be solved by putting

```
\newcommand{\dojapanese}[1]{%
   \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Japanese}#1\end{Japanese}\end{CJK}%
}
```

into the preamble of the document.
The new command can then be used successfully inside an bibliography file:

```
@Electronic{somesrc,
  author   = {\dojapanese{橋本}},
  title    = {\dojapanese{テスト}},
  year     = {2016},
  url      = {http://www.some-japanese-site.co.jp},
  language = {Japanese},
  urldate  = {2016-08-05}
}
```