# Using Japanese without \begin{CJK}

Tags: japanese

I use Japanese a lot. Is there a way I can just get Japanese to be in the document like latin characters? I don't want to have to use \begin{CJK}\end{CJK} everytime like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex)

Comment: This could afaik be achieved using `lualatex`.

Comment: Also ref. to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240515/59521

Comment: Is there a reason compilation is so slow?

Comment: [Leo Liu's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15524/94691) to the question you've shown contains several approaches other than the `CJK` package. If you are dissatisfied with the typeset speed of LuaLaTeX, (u)pLaTeX would be worth considering (most of the documentations available online is in Japanese though).