# Novel class error compiling (LuaTeX, and XeTex)

Tags: xetex, luatex, compiling, document-classes, compilation-error

## Edited question

I’d like to write a document with the `novel` class, which is installed on my distribution.

Because it seems I can’t make my own minimal working example, I took it from the [official web documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel-documentation.html#hA) from which I delete what I think was not useful:

```
% !TeX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{novel} % See list of class options; usually none needed.
%%% METADATA (FILE DATA):
\SetTitle{IMPORTANT: Provide Book Title} % Required for PDF/X.
\SetSubtitle{} % Default: empty.
\SetAuthor{} % Default: empty.
\SetApplication{LuaLaTeX with novel and microtype}
\SetProducer{LuaLaTeX with novel-pdfx and hyperref}
\SetPDFX[CGATSTR001]{X-1a:2001}
%%% DIMENSIONS:
\SetTrimSize{5.5in}{8.5in} % Sets width, height of your book.
% Default Media Size equals Trim Size.
% Rarely-used over-ride, except for cover artwork:
% \SetMediaSize[alignment]{width}{height}
% Default margins vary with Trim Size. Defaults for {5.5in}{8.5in}:
\SetMargins{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.5in}{0.75in}
%%% GENERAL FONTS:
% Percent at end of line is necessary, when writing font settings multi-line:
\SetParentFont[%
SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},% Effective when small caps requested locally.
Kerning=On, %
Ligatures=TeX, %
]{Libertinus Serif}
% Main text font automatically adds Numbers=OldStyle,Ligatures=Common.
% Default main font size is based on other layout settings.
% Varies from 11pt to 12pt. With all default layouts, value is 11.4pt.
% You may manually choose a different main font size:
% \SetFontSize{length}
% Default lines per page (main textblock) is calculated from other layout settings.
% When using all defaults, the calculated value is 35.
% If used, \SetLinesPerPage manually chooses the value:
% \SetLinesPerPage{integer}
\SetDecoFont{NovelDeco.otf}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math} % unicode-math
%%% HEADERS/FOOTERS:
\SetHeadFootStyle{1} % This style has headers only.
\SetHeadJump{1.5}
\SetFootJump{1.5}
\SetLooseHead{50}
\SetEmblems{}{} % Default blanks.
\SetHeadFont[\parentfontfeatures,Letters=SmallCaps,Scale=0.92]{\parentfontname}
\SetPageNumberStyle{\thepage}
\SetVersoHeadText{\theAuthor}
\SetRectoHeadText{\theTitle}
%%% CHAPTERS:
\SetChapterStartStyle{footer} % Equivalent to empty, when style has no footer.
\SetChapterStartHeight{10}
\SetChapterFont[Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.6]{\parentfontname}
\SetSubchFont[Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.2]{\parentfontname}
\SetScenebreakIndent{false}
%%% CUSTOM FONTS:
% \NewFontFamily[]{} % Optional command.
% \NewFontFace[]{} % Optional command.
% \CreateFontFeature{}{} % Optional command.
%%% OTHER:
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english} % polyglossia
\microtypesetup{config=novel-microtype,stretch=20,shrink=20,final} % microtype

\begin{document}
\clearpage % or \cleartorecto
\end{document}
```

Now the issue I have is that I get a bunch of `polyglossia` error messages when I compile it with LuaTeX such as:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: language * is not loaded. Please load it before us
```

```
! Package polyglossia Error: Could not retrieve key frenchspacing for language
```

and other error messages like so:

```
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
```

---

### Previous question that wasn’t clear for answers:

Everyone, I am new, so forgive the silliness of my question. I’d like to write a document with the `novel` class, which is installed on my distribution.

My minimal sample is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{novel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{•}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

I’m using Texmaker as my editor, and when I compile with LuaTex the first error I get is

```
! LaTeX Error: *** this package currently works only with XeTeX ***
```

But I don’t know how to make it work with XeTeX, because if I compile with XeLateX (is it the same thing?), then I can not compile with LuaTex and the following error appears:

```
! Class novel Error: Must compile with LuaLaTeX 0.95+.
```

Comment: You have not shown any input which makes it hard to tell you what is wrong with your input but you have written a document that can not be processed. You are using `\documentclass{novel}` so you have to use lualatex, but have used `\usepackage{something}` for some package you have not named which has to be used with xelatex.

Comment: I edited my question with the minimal sample.

Comment: oh `\usepackage{xltxtra}`  and `\usepackage{xunicode}` are not recommended even with xelatex, just delete them both

Comment: Do you want to print CJK characters in `novel` class? `novel` class is designed for print-on-demand, and so pre-configures almost everything, including fonts, and disables many commands, so that, for example, it prevents `luatexja` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240507/change-font-automatically-when-typing-cjk-characters-possibly-lualatex) from working. Depending on what you need to do, there may be workaround(s), but they will depend on the actual code you will be using at that point, and what problem you need to solve.

Comment: @Cicada I’m not sure what the CJK characters are... nevertheless, what I want is only to be able to write a short story with this class as it suggests is good for that purpose. I will not be doing anything special with my document; a pre-configured document will be perfect for what I need.

Comment: @Louis.vgn sounds like it should be OK. `novel` class is designed for immmediate printing/manufacturing a book, so the pre-configuring is very extensive, e.g., even the layout of the copyright page. If you need help with any of that, the documentation is at `...\texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/novel/novel-documentation.html`. CJK is Chinese-Japanese-Korean. But `novel` class imports `polyglossia` package for use with languages in general, so it depends what you want to type.

Comment: @Cicada I know, right? It should be ok, but the thing is that it isn’t working. I’ve had several looks at the documentation, but still nothing is working, it doesn’t compile and gives the bunch of errors I listed in the question. I don’t get it, I feel like I’m doing everything right, but it is not working unfortunately. I don’t know what else to do.

Comment: Start typing with `\documentclass{novel}\begin{document}Text goes here.\end{document}`. What happens? You must compile with lualatex - the `novel` class assumes that.

Comment: Better still: type the text using a plain class: `\documentclass{book}\begin{document}Text goes here.\end{document}`. Printing the text as a novel-sized commercial publication with `novel` class can be done afterwards, as a second step (and note: you will definitely have to set settings at the commercial  printing stage because of all the pre-configuring and sand-boxing `novel` does, even to fonts, headers, layout etc etc etc).

Comment: I did what you told me and the errors are the following:  `! Package polyglossia Error: language * is not loaded. Please load it before us`,  `! Package polyglossia Error: Could not retrieve key frenchspacing for language`,  `! Package polyglossia Error: Could not retrieve key direction for language "*".`,  `! Package polyglossia Error: Could not retrieve key indentfirst for language "*`,  `! You can't use '\relax' after \the.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130000/discussion-between-cicada-and-louis-vgn).

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown your input or enough of the error message to fully diagnose but you have a document like

```
\documentclass{novel}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The `novel` class requires lualatex but the `xeCJK` class requires xelatex so you get an error in all cases.

**pdflatex or xelatex**

```
! Class novel Error: Must compile with LuaLaTeX 0.95+.

See the novel class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.76 ...uaLaTeX only. No pdfTeX, dvips, or XeTeX.}
                                                  
?
```

**lualatex**

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty

! Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function.
(xeCJK)                         
(xeCJK)                         You must change your typesetting engine to
(xeCJK)                         "xelatex"
(xeCJK)                         instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex" or
(xeCJK)                         "lualatex".
(xeCJK)                         Loading xeCJK will abort!

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.43 ...sg_critical:nn { xeCJK } { Require-XeTeX } }
                                                  
?
```

The form of the last error is not quite as you show so the package requiring xelatex is not `xeCJK` in your case, but the basic issue is as shown.

There is essentially no fix for this you need to use a document class that works with xelatex or use a package that works with lualatex.

---

With the example added in the edited question you are in an easier case you are loading `xltxtra` and `xunicode` which are legacy xelatex packages that you can simply delete.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{novel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
% dont use these even with xelatex (and they only work with xelatex) \usepackage{xunicode}\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{•}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
% not with novel \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I left in `\setdefaultlanguage{•}` but that clearly errors as `•` is not a language. I assume your real document does not have that.